# In IN_APP_ITEMS_ON_VR, what means VR?

Tags: android

[BillingClient.FeatureType](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.FeatureType) defines a constant named

```
IN_APP_ITEMS_ON_VR
```

Its documentation describes it as 'Purchase/query for in-app items on VR.'

What does 'VR' stand for? 'Virtual Reality' doesn't make sense here, or does it?

I want to enable the users of my app to purchase one-time products. This constant seems to be the most likely of the constants in this class; but I want to know what it actually means.

Comment: Did you find out what it means? I'm curious too. Maybe `virtual reality` ?

Comment: [This](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.FeatureType.html#in_app_items_on_vr) is what the docs say, not much info.